# Python3: make csv from array of dictonaries choose the keys from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

we have one list which will have the key that value need to select

the list is

```
ll= ["name", "school", "age"]
```

the actual data is

```
dd= [{'p_name': 'school', 'p_value': 'abcd'}, {'p_name': 'escal group', 'p_value': ['PIppT SS PRaaOD']}, {'p_name': 'laptop', 'p_value': ['Dell']}, {'p_name': 'address', 'p_value': ['richmond street']}, {'p_name': 'name', 'p_value': ['subodh']}, {'p_name': 'age', 'p_value': ['33']}, {'p_name': 'friends name', 'p_value': 'leena'}]
```

Expected data

```
to_csv=[{'p_name': 'school', 'p_value': 'abcd'}, {'p_name': 'name', 'p_value': ['subodh']}, {'p_name': 'age', 'p_value': ['33']}]
```

And we want to convert it to csv

```
"school,name,age"
"abcd,subodh,33"
```

I have tried the below way but not working

```
for d in dict_data:
          for c in ll:
              hh={}
              if(d['p_name'] == c):
                  hh[d['p_name']] = d['p_value']
     print("The actual data\n\n\n\n\n\n")
     print(hh)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list of dictionaries `dd` and check if the value corresponding to key-`p_name` is in `ll`.

```
to_csv = [d for d in dd if d['p_name'] in ll]        

lst = [[],[]]
for d in to_csv:
    lst[0].append(d['p_name'])
    lst[1].append(d['p_value'] if not isinstance(d['p_value'], list) else d['p_value'][0])

out = '\n'.join((','.join(l1) for l1 in lst))
```

Output:

```
'school,name,age\nabcd,subodh,33'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension for that:

```py
to_csv = [d for d in dd if d["p_name"] in ll]
```

This will keep all the dictionaries `d` where `d["p_name"]` is in `ll`.